# How would I free these mallocs?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, free

I have this function to allocate memory to a matrix:

```
double **mmalloc(int r, int c){
    double **matrix = (double **)malloc((r)*sizeof(double*));
    for (int y = 0; y < r; y++){
        matrix[y] = (double *)malloc(c*sizeof(double));
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < r; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < c; x++){
            matrix[y][x] = 0;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

How would I free all the memory of the returned matrix? I have this function to free the matrix... I can free the rows of the matrix but I cant free the columns.

Here's the freeing function:

```
// Free all memory allocated for A 
void mfree(int r, int c, double **A){
    for (int y = 0; y < r; y++){
        free(A[y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And as usual, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to free all rows one by one, then the initially allocated column (that contains all rows)

```
void xfree(int r, int c, double **A){
    for (int y = 0; y < r; y++){
        free(A[y]);
    }
    free (A);
}
```

in this order.

```
double ** (Initial allocation)
  ↓
(double *)row0 → col0 col1 ...
(double *)row1 → col0 col1 ...
...
```

where each `row`*i* is made of (double) columns.

In order to completely free a dynamically allocated array of arrays, keep these rules in mind

- the number of *free*s has to equal the number of *malloc*s that was used to allocate the array and its arrays
- consider that if something is *free*d it is not usable anymore, even if it may work by chance (the behavior that follows such action is said Undefined Behavior). For example, if you `free(A)` first, you shouldn't `free(A[i])` since `A` - a memory space that contains a list of pointers - is not supposed to be allocated/usable anymore.
- therefore *free* first the innermost elements ("contained", eg `A[i]`) then *free* the "containers" (eg `A`).

Answer (score 2):

```
void xfree(int r, int c, double **A){
    for (int y = 0; y < r; y++){
             free(A[y]);  
    }
    free(A)
}
```

Comment: I agree, I used ringø's suggestion

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. I wrote the code by keeping in mind that A is a 3D pointer but A is a 2D pointer. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would 'cheat' and just allocate a contiguous block for your data, and then the second block to give you array access to your rows:

```
int main(){

    int r=3;
    int c=4;

    double* data = malloc(sizeof(double) * r * c);
    double** matrix = malloc(sizeof(double*) * r);

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<r;++i) { /* build the nice syntax accessor */
        matrix[i] = &data[i*c];
    }
    for (i=0;i<(r*c);++i) { /* you can fill/clear the whole matrix in one loop too */
        data[i] = i;
    }    

    // access data through matrix as a normal 2d array
    matrix[2][2] = 1.1;
    int x,y;
    for (x=0;x<r;++x) {
        for (y=0;y<c;++y) {
            printf("[%1.1f]", matrix[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // when done
    free(matrix);
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[0.0][1.0][2.0][3.0]
[4.0][5.0][6.0][7.0]
[8.0][9.0][1.1][11.0]
```

I don't think it even matters what order you call the two frees (provided you do both and no access in between) since one array just points into the other - you maintain separate references to each.

You could even store data and matrix together in a struct or something and then have a function that takes that struct and frees both areas (or both areas and then the struct itself).

Note: this seemed to compile and work but I don't write C for a living, get a second opinion before using in production code in case I've missed something